# GitHub not recognizing already cloned repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am using GitHub for windows client and have already cloned the needed repositories. It was working fine last Saturday as I checked-in my latest changes but today I opened GitHub, it's asking me for cloning the repositories again and not recognizing the already cloned repositories.

Any idea, how can I fix this. I am absolute new to using Git as repository (used TFS mainly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh!! silly. Not sure but thought of posting the findings as answer. Let me know if not helpful; will delete then.

On GitHub -> click on "Tools And Options" -> In opened window click on "Search Repository on your hard disk"

If repositories are already cloned then it will come up.

Click on "Add" to add them back to your cloned repository list.